# How to play mp4 files in VideoView in android

Tags: android, video, mp4

Can I play Mp4 video in android with android:minSdkVersion="8". I have looked arround but facing "This video cannot be played"

My code is,

```
    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    videoView.setVideoPath(path);
    videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoView.requestFocus();
    videoView.start();
```

Comment: That error also meant that the Video you are playing is not in the proper format.

Comment: No file is played in other apps , its mp4 file,                    String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +"/DCIM/test.mp4";

Comment: you mean are you able to play file in normal video player of device ?